# php preg_match url regex not working

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

I can't get this function working correctly:

```
function isValidURL($url){
 return preg_match('%http://domain\.com/([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)%', $url);
}
```

The url:

```
http://domain.com/anything-12/anything-12/
```

can contain numbers, letters and symbols _ -

I assume its to do with the first regex - as these work

```
    http://domain.com/anything12/anything12/

    http://domain.com/anything12/anything-12/

    http://domain.com/anything12/any-thing-12/

    http://domain.com/anything_12/any-thing-12/
```

As always all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to validate a url why not use `filter_var ($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` instead of a regex?  Or `parse_url()`.  Just curious.

Comment: It needs to match a single domain not any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to escape the `-` in the character class of your regex.
2. You need to anchor your regex so that tries to match the entire input string and not part of it.

The modified regex is:

```
'%^http://domain\.com/([A-Za-z0-9.\-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9.\-_]+)/$%'
```

You can shorten your regex by noting that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is same as `\w` and also there is a repeating sub-regex.

```
'%^http://domain\.com(/[\w.-]+){2}/$%'
```

Comment: I think it has to be `(/[\w.-]+){2}` because OP seems to need both the sub-expressions.

Comment: Hmmm it dosen't seem to be working in Google chrome or Safari ...any ideas? (works fine in FF and IE)